# Help with an econometrics/statistical modeling question

Tags: statistics

Show that $\hat{\beta} =\frac{1}{N} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}\hat{u_i^{2}}x'x $ is a consistent estimator for $E(u^2x'x)$

by showing:

$$\frac{1}{N} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}\hat{u_i^{2}}x'x = \frac{1}{N} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}{u_i^{2}}x'x + o_p(1), $$ 
where $o_p(1)$ is read "little oh p 1" and means a term vanishing in probability.

And we use the hints that:

1. $\hat{u}_i^2$ = $u_i^2 - 2x_iu_i(\hat{\beta}-\beta) + [x_i(\hat{\beta}-\beta)]^2$
2. $\hat{\beta} - \beta$ = $o_p(1)$
3. Sample averages are $O_p(1)$  read as "Big Oh P 1" (bounded in probability)
4. We assume all necessary expectations exist and are finite

I'm getting stuck with this. I know I must be missing some simple sort of substitution or there is some gap in my knowledge or understanding preventing me from making the necessary manipulations.

I would love if someone could walk me through this and explain the intuition a bit here.